# Autocad C# How to show data in a Dialog able edit and save

Tags: c#, .net, listview, autocad-plugin

After retrieving Xdata from an entity, I have a problem that how to show it into a dialog box for viewing, editing, and saving after changes.
I tried it on winform listview but failed.
How to call the even Form1 from another class.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private  void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView listView1 = new ListView();
        .
        .
        .
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```